# Location to file in tomcat webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, path

I try to write a log file which is located in my wabapp folder (`webapp/Files/Logs/Server.log`).
I am writing the log from java folder located: `minminyanserver/src/main/java/com/minyanserver/utilities/ServerLog.java`.
the full path of the log file is: `minyanserver/src/main/webapp/Files/Logs/ServerLog.log`.

the java code is:

`FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/Files/Logs/ServerLog.log");`

also I tried:

`FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("../../../../webapp/Files/Logs/ServerLog.log");`
and I get an exception:

`java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/Files/Logs/ServerLog.log`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to write to a location inside your webapp. A container may deploy your application without extracting it, and it may extract it to a read-only location. Always use `getResource` to load files from within your webapp package, and write your log and temporary files somewhere else, preferably configurable with JNDI and/or a properties file.